# Converting 32-bit TIFF to 8-bit TIFF while retaining metadata and tags in python?

Tags: python, tiff, imagej, imagej-hyperstack

I would like to convert several TIFF files with 32-bit pixel depth into 8-bit pixel depth TIFFs *while retaining metadata and TIFF tags*.

The 32-bit TIFFs are four-dimensional ImageJ-hyperstacks with TZYX axes (i.e. time, z-depth, y-coordinate, x-coordinate) and values in the range of [0, 1].

I can convert to 8-bit and copy over the metadata (using a very small sample image created in ImageJ):

```
import numpy as np
import tifffile

infile32 = "test.tif"

with tifffile.TiffFile(infile32) as tif:
    imagej_metadata = tif.imagej_metadata

a = tifffile.imread(infile32)
print(a.shape)

a = np.round(255 * a)
a = a.astype(np.uint8)

tifffile.imwrite("test_py-8bit.tif", a, imagej=True, metadata = imagej_metadata)
```

```
>>> (4, 3, 10, 11)
```

However, the pixel resolution (how many micrometers are in 1 pixel) is wrong, the "z" axis (`a.shape[1]`) is wrongly recognized as color channel, and the "time" axis (`a.shape[0]`) is wrongly recognized as z.

If I do this process manually in ImageJ, this problem does not occur, so I suspect the TIFF tags are necessary. I'd like a programmatic way to do it, so I can run the script on a cluster over hundreds of files.

Looking at the documentation of [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/), I know it's possible to also extract tags:

```
with tifffile.TiffFile(infile32) as tif:
    for page in tif.pages:
        for tag in page.tags:
            tag_name, tag_value = tag.name, tag.value
```

But how can I pass these tags to `tifffile.imwrite`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the `resolution` and `resolutionunit` properties and add the axes order of the image array to the `imagej_metadata` dict:

```
import numpy
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffFile('imagej_float32.tif') as tif:
    data = tif.asarray()
    imagej_metadata = tif.imagej_metadata
    imagej_metadata['axes'] = tif.series[0].axes
    resolution = tif.pages[0].resolution
    resolutionunit = tif.pages[0].resolutionunit

del imagej_metadata['hyperstack']
imagej_metadata['min'] = 0
imagej_metadata['max'] = 255

tifffile.imwrite(
    'imagej_uint8.tif',
    numpy.round(255 * data).astype(numpy.uint8),
    imagej=True,
    resolution=resolution,
    resolutionunit=resolutionunit,
    metadata=imagej_metadata,
)
```

Comment: This solves the issue of the resolution. But there is still some strangeness with the axes. When using drag-and-drop to open the image, the image appears to have only two dimensions with 12 frames (z*t). When opening via BioFormats import the axes are as they should be. If I convert to 8-bit within ImageJ drag-and-drop works.

Comment: I can reproduce that. It's risky to copy metadata verbatim. Try to adjust the `hyperstack`, `min` and `max` properties. I updated the answer.

Comment: ```del imagej_metadata['hyperstack']``` did the trick! Thanks!